# how to make life movie clip using actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, movieclip

I am using an ActionScript 2.0 for my project. I have a movie clip that is moving along the x-axis. My problem is, if that movie clip reaches the given boundary, it should automatically deduct one life. My codes doesn't work.

Here's my code for the timeline:

```js
var life:Number = 5;
lives = 3;
boundary = 280; 

var speed:Number = 1;
var boundary:Number = 280;


this.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
    if (clip._x > boundary) {
        clip._x -= speed;
    } else {
        clip._x = boundary;
        delete this.onEnterFrame; 
    }
}
if(lives == 0){
 gotoandstop(132);
}
```

Here's my code for moving mc:

```js
onClipEvent (load) {
    speed = 1;
    boundary = 280;  
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    if (this._x > boundary) {
        this._x -= speed;  
    } 
 else {
        this._x = boundary;
        this._visible = false;
  life -= 1;
        lifebox.text = life.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: But what happens after your movie clip reaches the given boundary? Does it stop? Does it disappear? Does it bounce?

Comment: the movie clip will disappear when it reaches the boundary and deduct a life.

Comment: And what happens after? Does another movie Clip appear? If you want your movie clip to disappear, you should remove it or put it elsewhere, because the hitTest will run continuously.

Comment: yes, there is another movie clip appear. Ahh, so i will not use this code `this._visible = false;`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to have a code for the timeline and a code for your movie clip.

On the other hand, if you want your movie clip to disappear, you should remove it or put it elsewhere, because the hitTest will run continuously.

**Main timeline code**

```
var lifes:Number = 5;
var speed:Number = 1;
var boundary:Number = 280;
var startX:Number = 320;
clip._x = startX;

this.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
    if (clip._x > boundary) {
        clip._x -= speed;
    } else {
        lifes--;
        clip._x = startX;
        if (lifes == 0) {
            gotoAndStop(132);
            delete this.onEnterFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. Where could I exactly put this code ?

Comment: @nesty santayo This code is for your timeline and it works here.

Answer (score 0):

Main timelines code is ok.

The mistake was in referencing. Here is corrected MovieClip code.

```js
onClipEvent (load) {
    speed = 1;
    boundary = 280;  
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    if (this._x > boundary) {
        this._x -= speed;  
    } 
 else {
        this._x = boundary;
        this._visible = false;
// use parent to refer variables and textfields declared, level up (in this case to main timeline);
_parent.life -= 1;
_parent.lifebox.text = _parent.life;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code works but when the movie clip reaches it's boundary, it will disappear but the life deducted continuously.

Comment: That's true. Life reduces continuously cos onEnterframe is Called all the time (i do not know how to remove That! if it's possible at all)

I suggest **not to place code inside instances**, never. Much less problems for you will be gathering all the control of your application from one place, by code. Use code even for placing instances on the screen etc.

Umh, for stopping lifes to reduse, just place a conditional:

    `(_parent.life >= 0)?_parent.life -= 1:null;`

it's a **short form** if statement for you to place intend of line where parent life is reduced (in the code of your instance)